# Number of faces in a planar graph bounded by odd length cycles?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose that every face in a planar graph is bounded by odd length cycles, then the number of faces of this planar graph is even. I want to prove this using Euler's formula, but not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:
$$2E =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k+1) F_{2k+1}$$

Since every odd length cycle face contributes its edges twice; by Euler's formula $V+F-E=2$ we have:

$$2V+2F-4 = 2E$$
$$2\left(V+F-2\right)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k+1)F_{2k+1}\right) $$

The left hand side is even. The right hand side is odd, when an odd number of odd length cycle faces appear, so it has to be even...

Comment: could you explain the first formula abit futher? I am not sure where the $2k+1$ came from

Comment: @LebronJames each triangle contributes 3 edges, pentagons 5 and so on.  $F_k$ is the number of $k$-gons in your graph. Each face contributes its odd number of edges twice due to the hand shaking lemma...

Comment: oh right, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I think I might not be understanding this correctly. Suppose we have the butterfly graph (which has 2 triangles). Then $2E=12$, but $(2n+1)=3$ and $F_k=2$, so the right hand side is $6$? Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the number of faces includes the outer face (outside the graph), so if there are two triangles in G, then G has $3$ faces.

Comment: @LeBronJames hmm interesting. I think the outer face has degree $6$, so the middle vertex counts twice. Then we have an even number of triangles, although the graph doesn't fit to your question anymore. Maybe that's a matter of definition, but I currently don't know. Maybe we can compare it with the graph displayed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbornane)...

Comment: @LeBronJames the outer ***has** an even degree $6$! Draw the dual graph to see that or check [this reference](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC8cGfo6XLAhUrOJoKHaGRDC0QFghWMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.itu.edu.tr%2F~gencata%2Fcourses%2FGT%2FGTlecture6.pdf&usg=AFQjCNERQvIcSJWYwmhOualcEN0RU6K9lg&sig2=MISF3HuJwam8HAKfAjv-pg&cad=rja) page 6...